# Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 1 - Will it be possible to upgrade to the standard release when it comes out?

Tags: 16.04

If I install Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 1 now, will it be easy to upgrade to the full release when it's out in late April?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no need to upgrade.

Install regular updates and finally you will be on the stable Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

As you will already be on 16.04 you will not need to upgrade to 16.04 as if you were on a different release from it.

If you continue to install updates using the Software Updater, or:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then when the full release of Ubuntu 16.04 is released, that will upgrade you to it.

Answer (score 0):

No separate upgrade required - just do the regular `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and you will be fine. *But* you should also be aware that you would be installing **beta** software, and it may have a few issues.